# Help regarding 義理

Tags: words, usage

In a the video game Tales of Destiny 2, the character Judas says to the protagonist Kyle:

> おまえがどんな結果を選ぼうと、僕にはどうこう言える義理はない。だが、忠告ならできる。

Under a rather literal translation:

> Whatever outcome you choose, I have no obligation to say this or that. But I can give you advice.

But this doesn't seem to make sense. 義理 here appears to have meaning close to 権利, but the closest I can find in the dictionary is [sense 2](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/58162/meaning/m0u/), which doesn't really seem satisfactory.

Here's the full context:

> また拒絶され、傷つくのが恐いのだろう？…僕も同じだった。傷つくのを恐れ、立ち止まってしまった。そして友や愛する人を失った。最後に僕に残されたのは…自らを隠す仮面だけだった。おまえがどんな結果を選ぼうと、僕にはどうこう言える義理はない。だが、忠告ならできる。…恐れるな、カイル！その先にこそ、おまえの求めるものがある。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

義理 doesn't mean 権利, while 義理 may mean something closer to 義務 (sense 2). In this context 義理 means 道理, 理屈, or more simply, 理由. The basic meaning of the sentence is "There is no reason why I can command you, but I can at least advise."

Comment: @Nothingatall Why is it embarrassing? People ask questions from video games here all the time.

Comment: @Blavius People have their reasons. On a related note, I apparently scared one user to create a new account by asking in comments if I had identified the game and the character the question was about after a long discussion related to understanding a monologue

Comment: It seems that 義理 has a sense of わけ。意味。 http://dictionary.infoseek.ne.jp/word/%E7%BE%A9%E7%90%86-53569#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88 . But it's archaic usage. It seems other native speakers agree me that 僕にはどうこう言える義理はない is a strange construction. https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/7348593.html

Answer (score 0):

> 僕にはどうこう言える義理はない

This sentence is simply bad Japanese. So you don't have to fret over it.
I think it's a cross between どうこう言う立場じゃない and どうこう忠告してやる義理はない.